# Google cloud shell problem with PHP built in server - could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 8080

Tags: php, localhost, google-cloud-shell

I can't get to work my simple index.php file on Google cloud shell. I start my server with command `php -S localhost:8080 -t test/`. Before that I navigate just before **test** folder. I click Web preview in upper right corner and get error: **Could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 8080** What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of working, and reseting... I just change from `php -S localhost:8080 -t test/` to `php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -t test`

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud Shell localhost resolves to both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses:

```
$ head -3 /etc/hosts
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

It appears that when this is the case, [PHP's builtin web server only binds to the IPv6 address](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#120449); however, Cloud Shell web preview connects to the IPv4 addresses. Your solution to bind directly to the IPv4 loopback interface (127.0.0.1) is probably the best, for now.